# What parameters are used when .addActionListener() is called?

Tags: java, button, this, actionlistener, frames

I've been learning quite a lot in Java recently but something has been really bugging me. I learned / was taught how to use ActionListeners when the program involves a constuctor, for example,

```
public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton button;

public test 
{
setLayout(null);
setSize(1920,1080);
setTitle("test");
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
button = new JButton("");
button.setBounds(x,x,x,x);
button.AddActionListener(this); //What can replace the this parameter here.
button.setVisible(true);
add(button);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test testprogram = new test();
    test.setVisible(true);
}
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickevent) {
    if (clickevent.GetSource() == button) { 
      //DoSomething
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look at javadoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anything which implements `ActionListener`.

You might want to consider not making your `JFrame` implement `ActionListener`: this means that

1. It is part of the class' interface that it implements `actionPerformed`; but you probably don't want other classes to call that directly.
2. You can only implement it "once", so you end up having to have conditional logic to determine what the source of the event was, and then handle it appropriately.

The alternative is to create a `button`-specific action listener:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent clickevent) {
    // Don't need to check if it is from button, nothing else
    // could have created the event.
  }
});
```

and remove `implements ActionListener` from the `test` class.

Answer (score 0):

It is instance of class which is going to handle `ActionEvent`.

From the [Documents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

> Register an instance of the event handler class as a listener on one
>   or more components. For example:
>
> someComponent.addActionListener(instanceOfMyClass);

Comment: What would be considered an instance of the class? I'm confused on this sorry. Like I would have initially expected it be something along the lines of   .addActionListener(actionPerformed);

Comment: It can be any class which implements `ActionListener`